# How can i choose from strings from an array randomly and set to textview

Tags: java, android-studio

I created array.xml in the res/values folder which contain 5 strings(avalaible_buses as the name of the array). pls how can i select strings randomly from this array and display it on textview. below is my attempt. seatNumber is the name of the textview.

```
public void seatNumber (View view) {     
String[] myArray = getResources().getStringArray(array.avalaible_buses);     
TextView seatNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seatNumber);     
Random random = new Random();     
seatNumber.setText(random.nextInt(myArray)); 
}
```

Comment: get a random index. decide between 0 and array.length -> that number - 1 is your index

Answer (score 1):

Break the question down into smaller parts.

Generate a random number between 0 and the last index of your array

```
// get a random number between 0 and array length - 1 inclusive (last index)
Random random = new Random();     
int index = random.nextInt(myArray.length);
```

Update the UI

```
seatNumber.setText(myArray[index]);
```

**Note**

The array is defined as

```
String[] myArray = getResources().getStringArray(array.avalaible_buses);
```

The way this is written it seems that the array resource (`available_buses`) deals with actual buses, not seats on a bus. If this is correct, I would have expected a text (ui) control like `busName`.

If you are assigning a random number to a passenger (seat number) you will also need to keep track of who gets on and who gets off so as to avoid assigning the same random number to two people. In other words, the array changes based on availability.

Answer (score 0):

Change line #5 like following.

```
public void seatNumber (View view) {     
    String[] myArray = getResources().getStringArray(array.avalaible_buses);     
    TextView seatNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seatNumber);     
    Random random = new Random();     
    seatNumber.setText(myArray(random.nextInt(myArray.length)));  // Line #5
}
```